# How to use ScreenSharing when you don't know the IP address of the target computer?

Tags: macos, vnc, computer-name, screen-sharing

I would like to use OS X ScreenSharing to connect to another Mac on my network.  I can do so by using Finder > Connect to Server, but I have to enter the Server Address: vnc://192.168.0.9 (the specific address).  My router is configured to terminate leases periodically, and I want to leave it configured to do so. I typically login to the router and can see a list of leased IP address along with resolved names.  In this case the target Mac is named, "The Family's Media Server" and I don't want to remove the spaces in the name.

I tried using the name in Finder > Connect..., vnc://"The Family's Media Server.local" (with and without quotes, and both failed.  Also, I can see the target system's full name in the Shared list in Finder from other systems in the network.

How can I connect using the system name so I don't have to keep looking up the the IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name converts to `The-Familys-Media-Server.local`. Spaces are replaced by "-" and special characters are removed. You should be able to connect by just using the name: [image: Connection Dialog]

For other computers, you can look in the sharing pane of System Preferences to find out exactly how the machine can be accessed:
[image: Network Name]